# .htaccess rewrite , parked domain on another site to read the proper domain name

Tags: domains, htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, parking

I have a parked domain `example.co.uk` on another domain name web-space in a folder and need to rewrite the domain name in the browser URL as it currently shows the other domain name while browsing and I need it to read example.co.uk.

When parking the domain the ISP automatically added this which works although displays another domain name.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.co\.uk$
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\:\/\/www\.otherdomain\.eu\/myfolder" [R=301,L]
```

Answer (score 2):

Remove the `R=301` from the end, so it's just:

```
RewriteRule ^/?$ "http\://www.otherdomain.eu/myfolder" [L]
```

That directive tells Apache to serve an [HTTP 301 (Permanently Moved) response](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.3.2), and hence the browser is served the rewritten location.  Without it, Apache just silently rewrites the request and serves the content in the rewritten directory with a standard HTTP 200 response.

Comment: yes i made those changes and it hasn´t made any visible difference.My main problem is, www.iq3d.co.uk is my site and it sits on my friends web space www.cabezon.eu/iq3d and I need the browser url to read only www.iq3d.co.uk/****   and not display the fact that i am resting the files on another site.